# UIView subviews updating visually but interact as though in previous state

Tags: ios, video, uibutton, hidden, behavior

I'm creating a UIViewController that houses some of RosyWriter's functionality, which I'm reworking to create a video recorder. The screen contains a title, a clipped-to-bounds subview that contains the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (so the sublayer CALayer of the video content is added into that subview, so I think it's quite deep-nested), and two buttons acting like a toggle button - in the form of Start and Stop buttons placed in the Storyboard for the UIViewController.

The Start button works fine, even though the video's preview layer is on screen and showing the camera. When I start recording, though, I switch the buttons round, making the Start button hidden and the Stop button hidden=false.

The start button works - this is pressed when the video preview is on-screen and updating, but the actual recording (grabbing samples in buffers and writing them to a file - nothing UIKit related as far as I can see) has not started.

*When the video recording is active, with the Stop button showing and the Start button hidden, the visible stop button isn't pressable, but the hidden start button can still be pressed.*

I've tried moving the Stop button above the UIView containing the video, in case the CALayer or something else stretches outwith the clipped UIView bounds. This doesn't help. The stop button always acts as though it's not enabled - but it is enabled, and nothing appears to overlap the button. The button works fine if the UIView containing the video (which, I'll reiterate, is lower than the broken button) is never shown.

Can anyone think why this'd happen? I immediately thought about setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay and tried just throwing some of those in, because it's almost as though the view had updated with my request to hide or show buttons, but an interaction layer hadn't updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I now think this is due to my ignorant use (or misuse) of dispatch queues. I'm still not sure how I was able to interact with buttons that aren't showing - perhaps it's because their own state change responds in part, immediately, and the rest can't take place except on the main queue (the visual refresh, for example).

So I solved the problem, in a sense, by forcing a particular asynchronous delegate method to be called on the main queue. This doesn't affect the operation of this particular step in my recording process.